# Box2d Revolute Joint vehicle with arm

Tags: java, android, box2d

I am creating vehicle like this on the image:

[image]

As you can see, there is:

1) main vehicle body (Red rectangle) 
2) wheels
3) vehicles arm (black rectangle)

Arm is connected with vehicles main body using Revolute joint in shown anchor center point, this arm can be moved up and down (with following angle limits) so as you can see it can move in 90 degrees only.

My question is, I am moving this arm by applying angular impulse, it works, I can move arm, but it keeps falling down to the default position. I am struggling how to "disable" joint, so arm can be moved only using my controller so its not affected by gravity, so player can move arm slightly up for example and arm should stay in this position, instead of falling down.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: I though about adding anti gravity force (opposite to the gravity) on every update to the arm, but not sure if it is best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to disable gravity impact is to set `gravityScale` to zero at b2BodyDef. But this parameter appeared only in last versions of Box2D, and, maybe, there is no such thing in your java port

Anyway, your idea with gravity isn't so good I think. It is not physic, not realistic and you can find some related troubles because of this. For example, what if some another force, except gravity, will impact the arm? It will cause all the same problem.

In my opinion, better way to make the arm - use motor of revolute joint. Some tutorial you can find [there](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/joints-revolute) in section "Revolute joint motor". You can enable/disable motor and change its speed run-time to simulate vehicle logic. In addition, it may be useful also change run-time upper/lower limits of the joint, to prevent arm moving when no action preformed. Another way to achieve this - set motor speed to zero, that will transform motor into some kind of friction force.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, unfortunately I do not have gravity scale feature. About your idea to with setting motor speed to 0, it does not work unfortunately, still the same - arm is falling down.

Comment: Do you tried adjust motor torque and max motor torque? These values must correspond arm weight.

Comment: You are right, setting max torkue to really big value in dead helped, thanks for help. Though I can not move arm any longer (by applying angular impulse) Is there any different way I can move my arm without having to for example enable/disable motor or manipulate with max tourque value? Once again thanks

Comment: How about change motor speed inside of applying angular impulse? When you need move arm up, set speed less then zero, down - more then zero, and if no move needed - zero. It is most logic solution I think.